# Will there be a Community Edition for Embarcadero C++Builder 10.4?

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-10.4-sydney

Does anyone know if, and when, there will be a Community Edition of C++Builder 10.4 that would enable us to experiment with the latest version of the compiler and the VCL?

I have had a lot of problems trying to upgrade 10.3 Community Edition with all the patches, and am really not sure what I have ended up with. Some of the improvements in 10.4 sound impressive, and it would be nice to start from something clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Feature Matrix for 10.4.2](https://www.embarcadero.com/features/feature-matrix) includes a footnote on some of the pages that states "Community edition planned for a future 10.4.x release. Current available Community Edition version is 10.3.3." So that appears to be the official position from Embarcadero.

Strangely the Matrix then outlines and contrasts the features of the Professional/Community Editions with the Architect/Enterprise editions in two columns without indicating the differences between the Professional Edition version at 10.4.2 and the Community Edition at version 10.3.3 - so it’s not much use to see what the differences are between the various Editions and the current Community Edition, and thus what we are missing.

I just hope that the use of 10.4.x doesn’t indicate a move towards using Roman numerals for point releases!

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this writing (Feb 10 2021), no information has been provided by Embarcadero regarding any release of a 10.4 Community Edition.